# How do I solve the mission "Day Zero"?

Tags: tropico-5

No matter what Island I play it on, at some point I plummet from like 60% to 40% approval and lose the votes. If I declare Martial Law to prevent the votes, the military coups.

How do I solve this mission? What is the best way?

Comment: A big part of that mission is keeping voter happiness up, have you tried digging into their happiness ratings during the election and trying to amp up whatever theyre mad about?

Comment: @Dpeif Yes, of course. But it seem to have little to no effect. For example, I took the worst performers of my sweatshops and raised their budgets, so people are well off. Didn't change much in the rating. I've built hydrophonic farms to enhance food consumption and enabled double rations as well as social security. It seems like the game is forcing me below a certain point. Election fraud also has little effect.

Comment: To the close voters: How is this too broad? It asks for the solution of a specific mission.While there can be different approaches, this is true for all games and we have lots of questions and answers here that deal with missions that are deemed hard by the asker. So explain yourself please.

Comment: The election fraud worked ok for me... got me like 5-6%. Combined with other 5-6% from max salaries and "beautification" buildings got me a 52%. A close call... but ok. But I think you need to combine tactics (fraud or salary alone won't cut it).